# Show Seconds in Vista Clock on System Tray

Tags: windows, windows-vista, clock

What is the best way to show seconds in the clock on the system tray in Vista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way to do it with the native clock.  Try [TClock Light](http://homepage1.nifty.com/kazubon/tclocklight/index.html), it looks a lot like the built-in one but with a lot more options.

**Edit:**  Apparently it doesn't work great on Vista, but the version discussed [here](http://www.greggdeselms.com/tclock.html) apparently does.  The download and install information is at the bottom of that page.  The guy is rather verbose.

Comment: The one in your edit does the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: I think it can be done in the region settings of Windows....

Comment: The TClock version by Stoic Jocker (mentioned in the edit) seems to work well in win7, choose the Segoe UI font to give it the same look as the default. (also put \n in your custom format to do line breaks)

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives for those who land here:

**[TClockEx](http://www.rcis.co.za/dale/tclockex/index.htm):**

- Freeware

  [image]

**[ClockDummy](http://www.dummysoftware.com/clockdummy.html):**

- Shareware

  [image]

**[Sarbyx TrayClock](http://www.rocketdownload.com/program/sarbyx-trayclock-24383.html):**

- Freeware

  [image]

**[Vista Clock](http://www.rocketdownload.com/program/vista-clock-120132.html)**:

- Freeware

  [image]

P.s. Now that we're talking about clocks. I just saw this one.... it's gorgeous, not really what you asked for (not for the system tray):

**[NOVACLOCK](http://www.novaclock.de/)**

[image]