# Is there a clock application with deciseconds (HH:MM:SS.d)?

Tags: windows-7, android, date-time, clock

You may wonder, But I am interested in a clock app that in addition to second show decisecond.

I deeply searched and could not find one yet, did you know any app (desktop gadget/system tray clock) for windows 7 or android app that show time like this: 11:51:32.1

Comment: A Google search for [`windows clock "deciseconds"`](http://google.com/search?q=windows+clock+"deciseconds") yields no relevant results. I think you've found yourself a unique idea! I'll meet you at the patent office! :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Horloger](http://amine5a5.deviantart.com/art/Horloger-V1-0-Final-206066131) supports milliseconds at least. Looks great:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows milliseconds.

Comment: @iglvzx: Those are just deciseconds with more precision :P

Comment: Thank a lot, However in was perfect if  it show just deciseconds and as big as other numbers. What about a program  for system tray clock?

Comment: @Reza: You could look into the skin format of Horloger. It seems trivial, maybe you can tweak it to look more like you want. Regarding system tray, I think [this](http://superuser.com/questions/62551/show-seconds-in-vista-clock-on-system-tray) is as far as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

Clock millisecond (for Windows)

from

https://sourceforge.net/projects/clock-millisecond/

[image]

It shows milliseconds but works at 10 FPS, so, it's perfect for deciseconds at least

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better answer

See it in action at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scxBddxr0gQ

It does only 10s of millisecond but it is the high accurary and refresh rate so far of all the other options

[[[image]]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scxBddxr0gQ)

save as ShowTime.bat, Thanks to reddit user u/illsk1lls

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Precise Time
MODE 30,3
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM pull a CarriageReturn from output of dummy copy error
FOR /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') DO SET "CR=%%a"
ECHO.
:TIMER
<nul set /p ".=%time% !cr!          "
GOTO :TIMER
```